# ARkit and Appthinning.plist error

Tags: ios, arkit, app-thinning, xcode9beta6

I have created a project under Unity with the ARKit plugin.

I have used the right versions. I compile from Unity, compile from XCode, archive and sent the (.ipa) on iTunes connect.

But, I received this error :

```
"Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Kouji". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

This bundle is invalid - Your archive contains paths that are not allowed: ( "AppThinning.plist" )

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team
"
```

My problem is that I found nowhere on internet a solution to these problems. Even on the apple developper website, this error is not listed.

If anyone can help me, it would be fantastic !

Comment: This looks to be an issue with Xcode 9 as of now. You're probably just going to have to wait this one out until Apple fixes it :/

Comment: Look through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361761/this-bundle-is-invalid-your-archive-contains-paths-that-are-not-allowed-ap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an other method.

In Xcode, instead of "Publishing the app", I exported it for the app store.

Then I used these commands to delete the file, create a new ipa and push it on iTunes connect with the App loader.

mkdir extract
unzip -qo MyApp.ipa -d extract
cd extract
ls
rm AppThining.plist
zip -qry ../MyApp.Fixed.ipa .

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this answer fixed my problem

Dont uncheck the `Strip Swift symbols` while uploading to AppStore

Check this image: [image]

[Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361762/4234949)

[Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84655)