# This bundle is invalid - Your archive contains paths that are not allowed: ( "AppThinning.plist" )

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode9, application-loader

We made an archive with Xcode 9.
We exported this archive with Xcode 9.
We successfully uploaded the app to iTunes Connect with Application Loader.
Yet, soon after, we got this message:

> This bundle is invalid - Your archive contains paths that are not allowed: ( "AppThinning.plist" )

This was not happening with Xcode 8.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

When you're exporting with Xcode 9 or later, they will ask you if you want to Strip Swift symbols:
[image]

Well, **don't uncheck it**! And the error will be gone.

Comment: But what if I don't wont to use this feature. As I understand, this increases build processing time.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich Did you fill a [radar](http://radar.apple.com) to ask Apple? Maybe they'll fix it in next Xcode release or iTunesConnect update.

Comment: @Coeur Not working for me, I am also facing this problem.

Comment: @Arunsharma please specify your version of Xcode (9.0 or 9.0.1) and... make sure you uploaded the correct exported archive, because it did work for so many others.

Comment: Why is the option to uncheck  "Strip Swift symbols" even exist, if doing so causes the "bundle invalid error"?

Comment: @RawMean I could copy past my first comment: "Did you fill a radar to ask Apple? Maybe they'll fix it in next Xcode release or iTunesConnect update."

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Correct me if I'm wrong but not striping the symbols should give me better (symbolicated swift part) if the crash occur.